# Show error like SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

i want to add data into database in laravel when i submit the data it show an error like (SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'donation.phone_no' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `phone_no` where `phone_no` = 03167777777)) donation.phone_no' not fount but my table name is members this is my migration I searched it in google several time but can't find appropriate solution. Any body help

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('member', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id', true);
            $table->string('name', 60);
            $table->string('father_name', 60);
            $table->string('cnic_no', 60);
            $table->string('phone_no', 60);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateInput($request);
         Member::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'father_name' => $request['father_name'],
            'cnic_no' => $request['cnic_no'],
            'phone_no' => $request['phone_no'],
        ]);

        return redirect()->intended('member');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, laravel's naming convention is lowercase plural for table names. Your table is `member` you need to make it `members` or explicitly set the table name in the model `Member`

Comment: i add members but it considered the column of phone_no as tabel rather then members  Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'donation.phone_no' doesn't exist in  phoe_no is not a tabel it is column table name is members

Comment: please post your model `Member`

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be issue in model. 
where you are using table name as ***donate***. rather then **member**.
please make sure in your Member model have same name of table which you are going to be use.
possible then please share your Member model.

```
 protected $table = 'member';
```

Full example of the model are below.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'member';
    protected $fillable = [
      ];
}
```

Make sure you are targeting **correct database** in **config/database.php** and **.env(environment)** file.
if correct then please try command.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: please make sure you have not using any many to many relationship with donate ?

Comment: okay make sure your database.php and env is targeting correct database ?

Comment: when i edit the form it shows the error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'donation.cnic' doesn't exist cnic is not a table